# How to look up and update the state of a record from a database in Apache Flink?

Tags: java, stream, apache-flink

I am working on a data streaming application and I am investigating the possibility of using Apache Flink for this project. The main reason for this is that it supports nice high-level streaming constructs, very similar to Java 8's Stream API.

I will be receiving events which correspond to a specific record in a database, and I want to be able to process these events (coming from a message broker such as RabbitMQ or Kafka) and eventually update the records in the database and push the processed/transformed events to another sink (probably another message broker).

Events related to a specific record will ideally need to be processed in FIFO ordering (although there will be a timestamp which helps detect out of order events too), but events related to different records can be processed in parallel. I was planning to use the `keyBy()` construct to partition the stream by record.

The processing that needs to be done depends on the current information in the database about the record. However, I am unable to find an example or recommended approach to query a database for such records to enrich the event that it is being processed with the additional information I need to process it.

The pipeline I have in mind is as follows:

-> keyBy() on the id received -> retrieve the record from the database corresponding to the id -> perform processing steps on the record -> push the processed event to an external queue and update the database record

The database record will need to be updated because another application will be querying the data.

There might be additional optimisations one could do after this pipeline is achieved. For example one could cache the (updated) record in a managed state so that the next event on the same record will not need another database query. However, if the application does not know about a specific record it will need to retrieve it from the database.

What is the best approach to use for this kind of scenario in Apache Flink?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can perform database look up by extending a *rich* function for e.g. a `RichFlatMap` function, initialize the database connection once in its `open()` method and then process each event in the `flatMap()` method:

```
public static class DatabaseMapper extends RichFlatMapFunction<Event, EncrichedEvent> {

    // Declare DB coonection and query statements

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
      // Initialize Database connection
      // Prepare Query statements
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap(Event currentEvent, Collector<EncrichedEvent> out) throws Exception {
      // look up the Database, update record, enrich event
      out.collect(enrichedEvent);        
    }
})
```

And then you can use `DatabaseMapper` as follows:

```
stream.keyby(id)
      .flatmap(new DatabaseMapper())
      .addSink(..);
```

You can find [here](https://github.com/dataArtisans/yahoo-streaming-benchmark/blob/master/flink-benchmarks/src/main/java/flink/benchmark/AdvertisingTopologyFlinkWindows.java#L249) an example using cached data from Redis.

Comment: Thanks. So what happens when Flink runs in a distributed cluster mode. Does it establish a connection from each node of the cluster?

Comment: You can have many `flatmap` instances depending on the paralleism you set. There might be more than one operator instances on each node (depending on the number of configured task slots).
For each parallel instance, the `open()` method is called exactly once and the `flatmap()` is called for each incoming event.

Comment: OK Thanks. I will have a go. By any chance do you know if it is possible to integrate Spring within Flink (or vice-versa)? There are things like dependency injection, entity manager auto-wiring etc. that would be very useful to use, but I can't seem to find any information online about people who did it (and if there are any pitfalls).

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the Spring framwork... You migh get answers asking Flink users mailing list : user@flink.apache.org.

Comment: Is there a way to handle this if you have a `WindowedStream`? I've noticed nearly all the method variants don't allow you to supply a `RichFunction` as they throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.